# multiple tool tips to be displayed on same page when we click multiple imagelinks

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to implement tooltips through javascript, 
like when we click on an imageLlink, tooltip should be displayed and it should have closebutton/close image to hide that tooltip.
like the same way i will have multiple images on my page, whenever i click on the images the respective tooltip should be displayed on the page when ever i want to close that then only it should close through close button on tooltip.

can any one help me on this, i need a sample example to implement this.

can we do it  through java script or will go for jquery ?

i am new for both.

Thanks in advance.
Kiran.

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery UI tooltip and override the default open method (on mouse focus) and bind that to a click function for the images. Also you can add a close button inside the tooltip and bind the Close method to that. Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-open

You can also check these jquery plugins.
http://tooltipsy.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTML CODE: 

   <div>
    <div class="tes_div">
        <img  class="test_img" src="http://sim02.in.com/c3aa4dc6853667b08505c83b605b3061_ft_xl.jpg" height="100px", width="100px"> </img>
        <div class="close_button" >"teststts" </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tes_div">
        <img  class="test_img" src="http://sim02.in.com/c3aa4dc6853667b08505c83b605b3061_ft_xl.jpg" height="100px", width="100px"> </img>
        <div class="close_button" >"teststts" </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tes_div">
        <img  class="test_img" src="http://sim02.in.com/c3aa4dc6853667b08505c83b605b3061_

    ft_xl.jpg" height="100px", width="100px"> </img>
            <div class="close_button"

 >"teststts" </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tes_div">
        <img  class="test_img" src="http://sim02.in.com/c3aa4dc6853667b08505c83b605b3061_ft_xl.jpg" height="100px", width="100px"> </img>
        <div class="close_button" >"teststts" </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tes_div">
        <img  class="test_img" src="http://sim02.in.com/c3aa4dc6853667b08505c83b605b3061_ft_xl.jpg" height="100px", width="100px"> </img>
        <div class="close_button" >"teststts" </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tes_div">
        <img  class="test_img" src="http://sim02.in.com/c3aa4dc6853667b08505c83b605b3061_ft_xl.jpg" height="100px", width="100px"> </img>
        <div class="close_button" >"teststts" </div>
    </div>

</div> 
  Jquery code 

$('.test_img').click(function(){


    $(this).next().addClass('testts_div');
});

$('.close_button').click(function(){

$(this).removeClass('testts_div');

});


AND CSS 


.testts_div{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    display:block !important;
    top:0px;
    left:20px;
}

.tes_div{

    position:relative;

}
.close_button{
    display : none;
}





in the div( class= "close button") . you can write close button div and you can show and hide it
```

Comment: Hi souravb, Thank you very much for your reply and i have tried the same in my jsf2 appplication, but it does not worked for me.i there any configurations requied for this like the plugins to add. i wrote this in xhtml file and the jquery is place  inbetween the script tags.   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        ... Jquery code
    </script>